# Python if statement issue and looping

Tags: python, if-statement

This is more a plea for help from the ubuntu community. I've done a lot of searches and reading and I guess I'm missing something. I'm trying to write a very basic program in python, here's the issue: I ask the question `raw_input("question" )`, then assign an `if` statement like so:
This is the error:

```
The debugged program raised the exception unhandled NameError
"name 'tx_rate' is not defined"
File: /home/Budget.py, Line: 47.
```

This is the code:

```
ans1 = raw_input("Do you know your tax rate?" )
if 'ans1' == 'yes':
    tx_rate = raw_input("What is it?")
    float(tx_rate)
    tx_rate = float(tx_rate)
    print "Thank you! Will use tax rate %s, instead of 0.15!" % (tx_rate)
elif "ans1" == "no":
    print "Okay, that's alright, we'll use 0.15 as the average tax rate!"
    tx_rate = 0.15
else:
    print "Sorry, incorrect value, please answer yes or no."
gross_pay = (hrs * rate) * 4.0
net_pay = gross_pay - (gross_pay * tx_rate) # [That last line is line 47]
```

The error comes from the variable for tx_rate never being assigned because weather I asnwer yes or no it runs the `else` option

So basically it asks me "Do you know your tax rate?" and no matter what I enter it takes me to the else option and displays the error. Which tells me I need to loop it back, how would I do that? So that when "else" is called, make it rerun the question, until if or elif are satisfied?

Comment: `if 'ans1' == 'yes'` - remove the `'` from `'ans1'`, you're comparing two different strings, hardcoded.

Comment: `if 'ans1' == 'yes'` / `elif "ans1" == "no"` -- you're comparing two strings there, not the value of the `ans1` variable and a string.

Comment: Where `hrs`, `rate` are defined?

Comment: Your title mentions looping, but there's no loop in your code. After printing the error message, your script goes on to use the variables that were never set, instead of looping back to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your code revised:

```
ans1 = raw_input("Do you know your tax rate?" )
hrs = 10
while True:
    if ans1 == 'yes':
         tx_rate = raw_input("What is it?")
         float(tx_rate)
         tx_rate = float(tx_rate)
         print "Thank you! Will use tax rate %s, instead of 0.15!" % (tx_rate)
         break
    elif ans1 == "no":
        print "Okay, that's alright, we'll use 0.15 as the average tax rate!"
        tx_rate = 0.15
        break
    else:
        print "Sorry, incorrect value, please answer yes or no."
        ans1 = raw_input("Do you know your tax rate?" )
gross_pay = (hrs * tx_rate) * 4.0
net_pay = gross_pay - (gross_pay * tx_rate)
print(net_pay)
```

And my output is:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Do you know your tax rate?no
Okay, that's alright, we'll use 0.15 as the average tax rate!
5.1
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Do you know your tax rate?yes
What is it?0.151
Thank you! Will use tax rate 0.151, instead of 0.15!
5.12796
>>>
```

Comment: It's feeding me an error on the lines "break". Also why would I put in "hrs = 10" if hrs is a variable?  Prolly should include the error huh?  : The file /home/Programs/Budget.py contains the syntax error 'break' outside loop at line 41, character 0.   I also get an error when I use the while command

Comment: I'll put `hrs = 10` because this variable is not set in this piece of code! To run it all variables have to contain values! And it work for me on Python 2.7.8. What is your Python version?

Comment: Nevermind, I've been up too long, working on too many things, thank you, I was able to make the code run, I also understand the "if" syntax a little better now so thank you for that as well! Thanks everyone for the help

Comment: Okay one thing though, when I tested the code it worked with yes and no however when I enter something invalid, it kicks out the "else" print indefinitely.

Comment: It seems that they don't let me use your own  code and modifying it. Sorry

Comment: @JerryWhite: Sorry! I have added the solution : `ans1 = raw_input("Do you know your tax rate?" )` in the `else` statement.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that `if` and `else` conditions are wrong - they compare the **string** `'ans1'` instead of the variable `ans1`.

Once that is fixed, there are a couple of ways to fix your problem. One way would be to use a `while` loop the continues until `'yes'` or `'no'` is supplied:

```
ans1 = None

while ans1 not in ['yes','no']:
    ans1 = raw_input("Do you know your tax rate?" )
    if ans1 == 'yes':
        tx_rate = raw_input("What is it?")
        float(tx_rate)
        tx_rate = float(tx_rate)
        print "Thank you! Will use tax rate %s, instead of 0.15!" % (tx_rate)
    elif ans1 == "no":
        print "Okay, that's alright, we'll use 0.15 as the average tax rate!"
        tx_rate = 0.15
    else:
        print "Sorry, incorrect value, please answer yes or no."
```

Comment: Okay I fixed the syntax error "ans1" = "yes" now I get this:  The debugged program raised the exception unhandled NameError
"name 'yes' is not defined"
File: /home/jerry/Documents/Programs/Budget.py, Line: 36                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 Also I tried the loop and it gave me a bug on the line : while ans1 not in ['yes', 'no']  highlighting while as the issue

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try defining tx_rate=0.15 before your if...else conditions. Because when your user inputs nothing for the first question where you ask for yes or no it directly goes to the else part where there's no tx_rate so giving you error "variable not defined"

Comment: That worked, the only issue I have now is looping, before, when I would force it to try to loop, it would reloop the "else" option until my IDE crashed, now it just skips it completly and prints the else option, but then finishes the application anyways closing it out without an error message, as if the program had run properly

Comment: @JerryWhite I'm not getting what you're trying to convey. Please show me the code